# TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

HTML:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="next()" class="timeline-right-arrow" tabindex="0">
    <i class="timeline-right-arrow-icon"></i>
  </a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.next = function () {
  $scope.timeLineScroll.next();
};

$scope.prev = function () {
  $scope.timeLineScroll.prev();
};
```

When I click `next` get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.next (TimelineController.js:139)
    at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12404)
    at angular-touch.js:472
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14466)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14565)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular-touch.js:471)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (jquery.js:3074)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle (jquery.js:2750)
```

TimelineController.js 139.line

Comment: `console.log($scope.timeLineScroll)` and what it returns?

Comment: Try it like `$($scope.timeLineScroll).next()`

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina 
it returns: Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

Comment: You should consider adding an explanation of your problem in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In this line `$scope.timeLineScroll.next()`, yours $scope.timeLineScroll is undefined that is why its throwing this error.